How do I cancel a long running task from a DELETE endpoint in ASP.NET Core?
I have an API to generate a long running task and a different API to fetch the result (can also be called to get a partial result).
An example:
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult LongRunning()
{
    var taskId = longRunningService.CreateTask();

    var progress = new ProgressDto
    {
        Id = taskId,
        Status = "created"
    };

    return CreatedAtAction("LongRunningProgress", new { id = taskId }, progress);
}

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProgressDto>> LongRunningProgress(int id)
{
    var task = longRunningService.GetTask(id);
    // Return based on task completionstate or partial result
}

[HttpDelete("{id:int}")
public ActionResult CancelLongRunning(int id)
{
    // How?
}

I liked the way this was strung together and made sense from a REST point of view. However I can't figure out how to cancel the task properly.
One way is for the service to also know about the CancellationTokenSource but that feels wrong?
Another way is for the Controller to know about a static CancellationTokenSource but that limits the controller to a single long running task at a time (which obviously is not feasible).
I know you can pass a cancellation token into the controller action, but that is for that singular action. It cannot be used for a different action. And it will be triggered on disconnect which is not a case here.
Is there an obvious answer I'm missing?
Thanks

I'd say there should be an API longRunningService.CancelTask(id). How it works is an implementation detail of that service, so we need to shift focus to that. Unfortunately, you didn't add any code of that.

^^ For example the service could maintain a ILookup<WhateverTypeOfTaskId, CancellationTokenSource> ....

What is the backing technology for your long running process? Does it support the cancellation token?

@Fildor So the service should have knowledge of the CancellationTokenSource? I was sort of dreading that answer :D
I have a working piece of code for the service but it looked janky so I wondered if there was another way of doing it.

Not exactly. The service should create and maintain its lifetime. You cannot use any outside cancellation context. You create that when starting the task and you get rid of it when the task completes. If cancellation is requested, you use it. That's basically it.

How do you implement your Service? Do you mean to stop the task when the application stops?
